# Can I just seal a leak in the shower?

Tags: shower, leak

I have a shower that's leaking from the corner. Basically, as can be seen from the picture, it falls through into the crack and then the water goes behind tiles and comes out the floor right outside the shower cubicle.

The house is 8 years old and I've just bought it. It doesn't look like there's any damage I can see from inspecting the wall. Should I just seal up the hole with silicone sealant? Do I need to somehow dry the inside behind the tiles?

Picture of bathroom
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xW0ckLSo4b0QXIdUqG6KpbL8GH0tSIom/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: I personally don't understand the details of a tile shower, but I do know there is supposed to be a water impervious membrane under the tile to prevent this type of leakage. AFIK the bottom of the shower and bottoms of the walls must be redone down to the slab and studs. If there is a home warranty, try to get this repaired under that. Quickly try to proceed through that channel before you try to seal it from inside the shower (which would be a band aid solution) .

Comment: What is on the other side of the wall at the leaking corner?

Answer (score 2):

As @JimStewart mentioned, in tile showers there is a waterproof "shower pan" usually either rubber, plastic, fiberglass or some other fabric that contains the water that manages its way through the grout joints.  If there is a leak in the pan, any attempt to fix it inside the shower would be futile.

It's hard to see what's going on from the picture, but if you say the water is making its way past the shower curb, you can try to strip all the old calk, re-calk and see if the water still leaks past.  If it does, you may need to tear up some tile for more investigating.